# What is the difference between english.stackexchange.com and ell.stackexchange.com?

Tags: discussion

What is the difference between english.stackexchange.com and ell.stackexchange.com?

Why two sites are built as English Language forums?

Comment: Posted to ELL as well: http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/22155/what-is-the-difference-between-english-stackexchange-com-and-ell-stackexchange-c

Comment: Yes, It's mine as well!

Answer (score 4):

**ell.stackexchange.com** is for people who are still learning the language. More basic concepts are covered there to help learners understand and use the language comfortably – with help from a native English speaker. **english.stackexchange.com** is intended and run more for native and fluent speakers of English where more advanced concepts can be covered.

Comment: the lines are extremely blurred my friend